# Syntax error on token "<=", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java, mysql

I'm attempting to fix a plugin I wrote a long time ago for [Craftbukkit](http://bukkit.org), but I'm stumped on one section. I've searched Google with little luck, and I've asked other Java developers only to hear that I shouldn't be using a for loop because it's rather basic, or that I'm using a boolean expression in the wrong place. Nobody will tell me ***how*** I can fix this, so I'll know for future references - Below is the class that throws the error:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;

public class Database
{
  private static String host = null;
  private static String port = null;
  private static String database = null;
  private static String table = null;
  private static String username = null;
  private static String password = null;
  private static String colUsername = null;
  private static Logger logger = null;

  public static void init(FileConfiguration config, Logger log)
  {
    logger = log;

    host = config.getString("DBHost");
    port = config.getString("DBPort");
    database = config.getString("DBName");
    table = config.getString("DBTable");
    username = config.getString("DBUser");
    password = config.getString("DBPass");
    colUsername = config.getString("ColUsername");
  }

  public static Hashtable<String, Object> getUserInfo(String user)
  {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + colUsername + " = ?";

    Connection connect = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    Hashtable<String, Object> userInfo = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
      stmt.setString(1, user);
      result = stmt.executeQuery();
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
      int i;
      for (; result.next(); i <= rsmd.getColumnCount())
      {
        rsmd = result.getMetaData();
        i = 1; continue;
        userInfo.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), result.getObject(i));i++;
      }
      return userInfo;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      logger.warning("Unable to load driver. Using default behaviour.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      logger.warning("Database error. Using default behaviour.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      if (result != null) {
        try
        {
          result.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (stmt != null) {
        try
        {
          stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (connect != null) {
        try
        {
          connect.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The error I encounter is in this part of the code:

```
  for (; result.next(); i <= rsmd.getColumnCount())
  {
    rsmd = result.getMetaData();
    i = 1; continue;
    userInfo.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), result.getObject(i));i++;
  }
```

Where I get the error "Syntax error on token "<=", invalid AssignmentOperator"

How should I go about fixing this, and how can I improve it?

EDIT #1:

This is my updated code, according to Jon's answer:

```
try
{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
  stmt.setString(1, user);
  result = stmt.executeQuery();
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
  while (result.next()) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
          rsmd = result.getMetaData();
          userInfo.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), result.getObject(i));i++;
      }
  }
  return userInfo;
}
```

Comment: Go read the syntax of a classic `for` loop. What is the third expression supposed to be?

Comment: `for` loop java `->` `for (initialization; termination;
     increment)`

Comment: In addition to the `for-loop` being improperly setup, you're calling `continue` unconditionally. This means the `userInfo.put` statement will never be executed.

Comment: Hi guys, I updated the post - I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically this is the wrong way round:

```
for (; result.next(); i <= rsmd.getColumnCount())
```

It should *possibly* be:

```
for (; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); result.next())
```

Although more likely, you actually want:

```
while (result.next()) {
    // This outer loop is executed once per row        

    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        // This inner loop is executed once per column (per row, as it's
        // within the outer loop)
    }
}
```

Having said that, you're not even initializing `rsmd`, which doesn't help. I suspect you may want to call [`ResultSet.getMetadata()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29), e.g.

```
rsmd = result.getMetadata();
```

For reference, the three parts of the `for` statement declaration are as follows:

- The first part (empty in your case) is performed once, as initialization
- The second part is a condition to check on each iteration; the loop ends when the condition evaluates to `false`
- The third part is a statement is a step to take at the end of each iteration

See [section 14.14.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) or the [`for` statement part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details.

Comment: What should I initialize the rsmd as? Null or should I use an integer?

Comment: @Winter: You should be getting the metadata of a result-set presumably. It sounds like you should possible take a step back and start again... you shouldn't have code that you don't even understand what it's trying to do.

Comment: I updated my original question - I knew it should've been metadata so I'm not sure why I asked that.. How is my updated code now?

Comment: @Winter: Well you should close the statement and connection, but aside from that it's probably okay. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in the last part of a `for` loop:

```
i <= rsmd.getColumnCount()
```

Perhaps you meant this?

```
for (; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); result.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax of a `for`-loop:

```
  for (any; boolean; any)
```

your's is

```
  for (any; any; boolean)
```

Just change the order.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, because expressions like `i = 1` and `i++` aren't `void`, they have a non-void type.